# How to change fontsize in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I have to create a content with font as Times New Roman and font size as 16.How to create using python script ?

### My sample script

```
import xlwt
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(encoding = 'ascii')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('My Worksheet')
font = xlwt.Font() # Create the Font
font.name = 'Times New Roman'
style = xlwt.XFStyle() # Create the Style
style.font = font # Apply the Font to the Style
worksheet.write(0, 0, label = 'Unformatted value')
worksheet.write(1, 0, label = 'Formatted value') # Apply the Style to the Cell
workbook.save('fontxl.xls')
```

Answer (score 16):

You set the font's height in "twips", which are 1/20 of a point:

```
font.height = 320 # 16 * 20, for 16 point
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the comment says that you do, you don't actually apply the style you defined!
Use the `style` keyword in the `write()` call:

```
worksheet.write(1, 0, label = 'Formatted value', style = style) # Apply the Style
```

Comment: thanks Junuxx. I have applied style to the code and worked well.

Answer (score 1):

just add this

```
style = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1,height 280;')
```

Answer (score 0):

style0 = xlwt.easyxf('font: bold 1,height 260, name Times New Roman, color-index red')

You should be user like if you want font change and color also use may be it will be work on excel

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for info on how to format code.